# How to add an index to a list of a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, for-loop

I want to sort a List within a List that i currently have which isnt the issue, its that I believe I have saved the values as a single index in the array, but need the finishTime to be a seperate index as I would need to sort the arrays by this value. The context of this code is a simple Athlete race data entry form.
The code is below

```
import time
datasets= []


for i in range(1, 3):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = input("Is the athlete male or female ")
    athlete = input("What is the athletes name ")
    finishTime = input("What was the finishing time ")
    dataset = ("Gender =", gender, "|" ,"Athlete =", athlete, "|","Finish time", finishTime)
    datasets.append(dataset)






for s in datasets:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("")
    print(*s)
```

It should look like this

```
>Male John, 9
>Female Sarah, 7
```

As you can see they should be two different indexes so that I can then sort the lists within the list by the number on the end.

Comment: You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: Why not use a dictionary or a named tuple for the dataset, and a list of these for the datasets?

Comment: It would need to be sorted by the finishingTime however, I think theres only one index for each array. It would need another index which would be the finishingTime from where it can be sorted, Im having trouble with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using your list of lists, use either [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort) to sort the list in place or [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) to get a new sorted list. Use the `key` argument to either function to sort on the last element of the list. If you need the items sorted from largest finish time to shortest, set `reverse=True`:

```
datasets.sort(key=lambda dataset: float(dataset[-1]), reverse=True)
```

this will sort the list based on the numeric floating point value of the last item of each nested list. You might prefer to use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)s instead of `float`s to avoid any loss of precision, particularly if you need to perform calculations on the times.

I think, however, that you'd be better off using a dictionary, named tuple, or even an ordinary tuple instead of the inner list. Here's an example using a dictionary:

```
datasets = []

for i in range(1, 3):
    dataset = {}
    print("Inputing Data for Lane", i)
    dataset['lane'] = i
    dataset['gender'] = input("Is the athlete male or female ")
    dataset['athlete'] = input("What is the athletes name ")
    dataset['finishTime'] = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
    datasets.append(dataset)

datasets.sort(key=lambda d: d['finishTime'], reverse=True)

for dataset in datasets:
    print('{} {}, {}'.format(dataset['gender'], dataset['athlete'], dataset['finishTime']))
```

Answer (score 0):

First use a proper data structure - this:

```
("Gender =", gender, "|" ,"Athlete =", athlete, "|","Finish time", finishTime)
```

is mixing data (the `gender`, `athlete` and `finishTime` values) with presentation stuff, and is barely usable. Either just store the values ie:

```
 datasets.append((gender, athlete, finishTime))
```

you know that for each "row" in `datasets`, `row[0]` is the gender, `row[1]` is the name and `row[2]` the time.

```
row = datasets[0]
print("Gender : {}".format(row[0]))
```

or use dicts if you want something more explicit:

```
 datasets.append(
     {"gender": gender, "athlete": athlete, "finishTime": finishTime}
     )
```

so for each row you can get the values by key instead of index:

```
row = datasets[0]
print("Gender : {}".format(row["gender"]))
```

Then you very certainly want to make `finsihTime` an integer - `input()` returns a string, and string don't sort the same way as integers:

```
>>> lst = ["15", "2", "21", "3"]
>>> sorted(lst)
['15', '2', '21', '3']

>>> lst2 = [15, 2, 31, 3]
>>> sorted(lst2)
[2, 3, 15, 31]
```

Then you only have to pass the proper `key` callback function to `sorted()`. If you use tuples:

```
>>> datasets
[('male', 'foo', 15), ('female', 'bar', 11)]

>>> sorted(datasets, key=lambda row: row[2])
[('female', 'bar', 11), ('male', 'foo', 15)]
```

If you use dicts:

```
>>> datasets
[{'gender': 'male', 'athlete': 'foo', 'finishTime': 15}, {'gender': 'female', 'athlete': 'bar', 'finishTime': 11}]
>>> sorted(dataset, key=lambda row: row["finishTime"])
[{'gender': 'female', 'athlete': 'bar', 'finishTime': 11}, {'gender': 'male', 'athlete': 'foo', 'finishTime': 15}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
datasets= []


for i in range(0, 3):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) # female|male check missing...
    athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
    finishTime = str(input("What was the finishing time "))
    dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
    datasets.append(dataset)





print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format("Gender","Athlete","Finish time"))

ds = sorted(datasets, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=False)

for s in ds:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
```

Comment: Could you provide a brief explanation on what you added so i can further understand this.

Comment: Changed to list format because sorted() function works only with it. All inputs are added to datasets as string (so sorting by dataset[2] / finishTime) is according to string type, not time or int. So leading zeros are important for finishTime ("01:00" is not same as "1:00"). Changed output to formatted string in order to get tabulated output.